# Do I need a different html page for printing?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've got a page that is printer friendly except for the header and footer. Can I add a print button that prints only the body of the page, and without the colored background? Or do I need to link them to a new page, and then have them click print again? I'd rather not introduce these extra steps if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do I need a different html page for printing?

Not necessary. You could use a different [print CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) which will specifically be used when printing. Inside this CSS you could personalize the look of different elements on your page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

The `media="print"` means that this CSS will be applied only when printing.

You might also checkout the [print.css](http://printstylesheet.com/) library.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to take a look at using a print stylesheet.

Here is a link which may help

http://line25.com/tutorials/handy-tips-for-creating-a-print-css-stylesheet

This is the route that I would suggest this way you can keep your stylesheets separate for screen and print.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I add a print button that prints only the body of the page, and
>   without the colored background?

You can set printer-specify styles via:

```
@media print {
.print {
    background:#fff;
  }
}
```

Apply `print` class to elements you want to change the behaviour of in printing.

Comment: That's a great tip!  I know it should probably seem obvious... but it can really help to identify on page with the `.print` class.  Good show!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new print-specific stylesheet, and in that stylesheet, hide any elements you don't want to appear when users print your page.

Here's a handy link on how to do that:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200001.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all through CSS, just set the media to print.

```
@media print
{
    /* Print specific styles go in the braces */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a [print media stylesheet](http://meiert.com/en/blog/20070221/print-style-sheets-the-basics-for-no-excuses/).

No need for adding your own button or creating duplicate pages. The browser's print controls are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to write print.css and specify that what you want to print and what you dont want.

See the links

- http://printstylesheet.com/
- http://line25.com/tutorials/handy-tips-for-creating-a-print-css-stylesheet
- http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/05/how-to-create-a-simple-print-css-for-your-site/
- http://www.intensivstation.ch/en/css/print/

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do (as Darin pointed out) is to add a CSS file for your print layout.  You need to make sure your CSS file is only called for printing by using the correct `media` type:

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually do it with some jQuery:

```
$(function(){  
// Hook the print link
 $( "a" ).attr( "href", "javascript:void( 0 )" ).click(function(){
// Print the DIV that you want to be printble
// Maybe you want to change the style of that printable div.
  $( ".printable" ).print();
// Cancel click event.
return( false );
 });
});
```

The idea is that you have a div that want to be printable and you hook the print button and do whatever you want with that div, and then print it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
@media print {
    body {
        background-color: white
    }

    div.header,
    div.footer {
        display: none
    }
}
```